# Labels and text inside Text Field becoming white automatically for iOS 13 Dark mode

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

My app works fine for iOS versions below 13.0 but when i updated the device to iOS 13 and chose Dark Mode, the labels are going white(which were black earlier) automatically which is not the case with Light mode (in which it is working fine, black labels remain black).

Anyone else experiencing the same and is there any fix for the same so far ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[image: Label Color]

Previously the `default` color of the `UILabel` was `Black Color`, but since iOS 13, the default value is `LabelColor` witch is a *Semantic Color* name from system *UI Element Colors*. To make it always black, change the color to `black` (not default). But be aware that the background color may change to black (from white) similarly.

Also you can **eliminate the dark mode** entirely by setting the UserInterfaceStyle on main window:

```
window!.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
```

**Note**: Window where in `AppDelegate` until iOS 13, and now it is in `SceneDelegate`.

Answer (score 29):

if you are using `System` Color than it will automatically change in dark mode. so you can use Custom Color in Application.

Or you can set key `User Interface Style` and value `Light`in `Info.plist` file.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

```
TextField(placeholder, text: self.$value)
                .colorScheme(.light)
```

You should add colorScheme attribute to avoid the textfield from dark mode.

Answer (score 5):

It's because your label's text color is set Default. In dark mode default color for text label is white and for view is black

Answer (score 2):

> Change textField text color to black (**don't leave default color**) and
>   place holder color using below code

```
yourTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Password", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.lightGray])
```