# How to solve TextField text Not displaying in IOS Version 13.2.3?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode10.2, ios-darkmode, ios13.2

I create an app in `XCode 10.2`.
Currently, Apple released a new OS version `13.2.3`, I update ios Version in a real device and I check my app in the real device.
not displaying text in my `textField`
How to fix this.
[image]

**Anybody can help me**.

Comment: just set `textColor` on your `UITextField`to e.g. `.black`

Comment: see this for help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58061378/labels-and-text-inside-text-field-becoming-white-automatically-for-ios-13-dark-m

Comment: default color are black set in textField proparty @imike

Comment: Your phone settings is in dark mode

Comment: your device has dark mode enabled. if you don't want to apply dark mode in your app then add below code to your app `window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light`

Comment: @DixitRathod same code is in Objective C?

Comment: @Nikunj `self.window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = UIUserInterfaceStyleLight;` this is for objective c. you can add this to your AppDelegate didFinishLaunching method

Answer (score 4):

**If your app not supporting Dark Mode:-**

you can Disable dark mode in your entire app by adding the following key-value in your Info.Plist.

```
UIUserInterfaceStyle =  Light
```

**If your app supporting Dark Mode:-**

In iOS 13 Dark mode Your Text color will not be visible. If you didn't set it. If you assign System colors dark mode and light colors will change automatically.

```
@IBOutlet weak var textFeild: UITextFeild!
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                textFeild.textColor = .label // System Color
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
              textFeild.textColor = .black
            }
}
```

or For custom colors, you can use callback method in UIColor

```
@IBOutlet weak var textFeild: UITextFeild!
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
                if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                     let dynamicColor = UIColor { (traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIColor in
                         if traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark {
                            return darkColor
                         } else {
                            return lightColor
                         }
                     }
                    UILabel().textColor =  dynamicColor
                 } else {
                     // Fallback on earlier versions
                UILabel().textColor =  lightColor
                 }
}
```

You can set this in storyboard itself.

[image]

Comment: Please suggest me where to use this code.@Manikandan

Comment: In your Viewcontroller, Apply these changes to your textField. Or you can set this in the storyboard itself.

Comment: I have updated my answer. let me know if you have any other doubts in my code.

Comment: Do you support dark mode in your app?

Answer (score 2):

Change the appearance of your device to a light mode and see if the problem is solved. If yes, then you should set the `textColor` of the text relative to the given appearance mode.

You can add new `Color Set` in `Assets.xcassets`, like this:

[image]

and the color will change automatically relative to the selected appearance mode.

**Hope this will help you!**